# Location updates in background

Tags: background, cllocationmanager

Currently, in my app, this is what I currently do:

- When the user triggers, ViewController-A (VC-A) startsMonitoring for GPS location of the user using either startUpdatingLocation or startMonitoringForRegion depending on the phone-model
- VC-A is also the delegate for CLLocationManager
- Currently, the monitoring happens in foreground - i.e. the app has to be running.

In order to get the location updates in background, this is what I have read and understood so far….

- separate the CLLocationManager delegate methods info a newClass and implement the delegate methods in the newClass
- VC-A then should use an instance of newClass to initiate the monitoring
- when newClass receives update and when the condition is me to notify the user, 
       - send localNotification if app is in background  or play alertSound if app is in foreground
       - stop monitoring

Do I need to do anything special in AppDelegate.m file?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the callbacks when your app goes into the background. I'm assuming from your question you are doing region monitoring for current devices, and just working out the location details for older devices?

If this is the case, you need to implement a locationManager in your AppDel as well as handling the callbacks for -didEnterRegion and -didExitRegion as well as the callbacks for the -significantLocationChange callbacks.

I just implemented a setup very similar (but I bailed on older devices). The key is creating a locationManager inside the AppDel to handle the callbacks.

If your app is in the foreground, the locationManager you use to create the regions or monitor location work just fine. But once you hit the background, you need to trigger the -monitorForSignificantLocationChange to save batter and handle any callbacks for it.

Comment: I depend on regular updates for short trips - therefore, I have to use "startUpdatingLocation" even in background.  For long trips,  user has a choice of using "startMonitoringSignificantChanges" - and on iPhone4 and later, the user can use RegionMonitoring.  I've read that the last two depend on cell towers and readings may not be accurate sometimes.     To come back to my question, I am going to take up your advice - but still have a question.  Will the AppDelegate just start/stop the monitoring only and the newClass implement the didUpdateToLocation:newLocation: delegate method? === Thanks.

Comment: It will depend on how you set it up. From the background, will call the implementation of didUpdateToLocation inside your AppDelegate. You have the option of calling to your other class to perform other logic, set new type of location monitoring, or whatever you need. The AppDel just catches the callbacks, what you do after that is up to you. Even though the region monitoring is based on cell towers, wifi, and other apps, it has proven to be more than accurate enough for my use.

Comment: In the small town that I am in, there are not enough cell towers...therefore, I haven't had good experience testing w/ RegionMonitoring.  I will have to go blind w/ it.  But - again - many thanks